# How to use application model inside partial of route?

Tags: ember.js

I think this should be a really easy fix, i just cant figure it out.
I have this model in my ApplicationRoute:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {
      sideNav: data.side, 
      breadcrumbs: Util.breadcrumbs()
    }
  }
});
```

application template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application"> 

    {{outlet}}

</script>
```

overview template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="overview">

    {{partial side}}

</script>
```

_side partial:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="_side">

    {{#each model.side}}

        <i {{bindAttr class="iconClass"}}></i><p>{{label}}</p>

    {{/each}}

</script>
```

When I load my overview route, the stuff in there loads, but the application model is not applied to the side partial like I would like it to be... there may be a better way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two problems:

1. You are binding to `side` instead of `sideNav` inside your partial.
2. You're trying to access the model of `ApplicationRoute` inside of the `overview` template (which presumably has its own route and controller)

Partials don't change context, so they don't add any complexity on their own. For instance, if we restrict ourselves to the `application` template, the following will work:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return {
            foo: 'bar'   
        };
    }
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{partial partial}}
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_partial">
    {{foo}}
</script>
```

However, if you want to get at the `application` model inside of a nested route, you'll need to ask for it. For example, inside of the (default) `index` route, you could add the following:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.modelFor('application');   
    }
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{partial partial}}
</script>
```

[You can see both examples in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmacleod/fDVNg/).